# Deluge Daemon fails to start on Ubuntu 15 systemd error: code=exited, status=203/EXEC

Tags: server, permissions, bittorrent

Trying to install deluge by [following this guide](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/systemd) on a new Ubuntu 15.10 VM. I have looked at the two most likely linked questions, but I can't discern an answer and the error message is different from the one I get.

When I run: -

```
systemctl start deluged
systemctl status deluged
```

I get: -

```
systemd[1]: deluged.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon.
systemd[1]: deluged.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon.
systemd[1]: deluged.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: deluged.service: Failed with result 'start-limit'.
```

Deluged web works fine, but I can't get this running at all. I've not fiddled with the config file at all, except to change the unet mask to something a little more permissive.

Any help gratefully received, thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem until I took out the logging flag...

Comment: I ran into this as well, and turned out that I hadn't actually installed deluged! I had run `apt-get install deluge`, but I needed to also run `apt-get install deluged`

Answer (score 4):

I had this on Debian today. Took me a while, but found that it was due to a broken Setuptools install in Python. Try:

```
        sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade
        wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
```

Comment: Absolutely the right answer. Not only did this fix the `start-limit` issue, it also led me to discover solutions to fix other issues I was having post-Jessie upgrade by updating many python packages (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip). Thanks!!

Comment: Bizarrely Will, I just got notified of this, so I will spin back up the server in question and give your fix a go! Thanks for the help.